# review summary box in magento - layout issue on different pages

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

any ideas why the review-summary box looks different on my products-detail-page than on review-page?
I also need to enter some extra stuff on product reviews page, like a link back to the product page. Im not shure which template file / xml has to be changed as I already changed the view.phtml and had minor success on the reviews-page with that.

any ideas?

[Summary on a product details page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrTmo.png)

[Summary on reviews page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udcwS.png)

Comment: you can use template path hints for checking which file need to be edited....

Comment: jupp, I tried that. Thing is, I can see which template is used for the reviews box, but I dont know why it is used - I can not for example change the elements class on the review page like I did in view-phtml beause I dont know where the review page is assembled - it grabes different tempalte files for the review page and I dont understand why

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Thanks, ill consider that.
sPanse